# Scala JSON deprecated in 2.11 - Is Argonaut as easy as scala.util.parsing.json?

Tags: json, scala, scala-2.11, argonaut

Parsing a JSON string like `"""["test",["aaa", "bbb", "ccc"]]"""`

is easy using `scala.util.parsing.json`:

```
// def jsonResponse = scala.io.Source.fromURL("http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=opensearch&search=test").mkString
def jsonResponse = """["test",["aaa", "bbb", "ccc"]]"""

def responseStrings = scala.util.Try[List[String]] {
  val Some(List("test", words: List[_])) = scala.util.parsing.json.JSON.parseFull(jsonResponse)
  words.map{case w: String => w}
}

responseStrings.get foreach println
```

prints

```
aaa
bbb
ccc
```

**How can I do this in such an easy way using [Argonaut](http://argonaut.io/)?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heres how you would do this in Argonaut which doesn't rely on catching Match Error exceptions in the Try block.

```
object Argo {
  import argonaut._
  def argoTest(): Unit = {
    val input =  """["test",["aaa", "bbb", "ccc"]]"""

    val js: Option[List[String]] = for {
      json        <- Parse.parseOption(input)
      outerArray  <- json.array
      innerArray  <- outerArray match {
                      case h :: arr :: rest => h.string.filter(_ == "test").flatMap(_ => arr.array)
                      case _ => None
                    }
    } yield innerArray.flatMap(_.string)
    println(js)
  }
}
```